# Turn call back into arrow function

Tags: typescript

I'm writing TS and I have the function below :

```
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + port);
});
```

I'm learning about arrow functions - how I can turn this into TS arrow function?

I tried:

```
app.listen(port)  => {
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + port);
};
```

But this doesn't compile.  Any ideas?

Comment: `app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + port);
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the empty parameter list `()`

```
app.listen(port, ()  => {
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + port);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As your function is having a single statement, you can skip the curly braces as below:

```
app.listen(port, ()  => console.log("Express server listening on port " + port));
```

Curly braces are mandatory for the multiline statements.